# Editorconfig file with "indent_size = space", valid syntax

Tags: editorconfig

I have an editorconfig file that has `indent_size = space`, is that a valid syntax, and if so what does it mean?  I looked at https://spec.editorconfig.org/index.html?highlight=indent_size#supported-pairs and it mentions tab but not space.  I looked for an online validator but could not find one.

Is the file just wrong?